# Why does the daemon say that I'm now syncronized with the network while I'm still missing some blocks?

Tags: synchronization, daemon

This is what I observed:

[image]

P2P2, P2P4, and P2P5 have more blocks than me. There's also a [P2P6] message without any indication of block height, and right thereafter the message that I'm now synchronized with the network.

Does this mean that P2P6 just does not have any newer blocks than me?

But when I know from other peers that there are more blocks, shouldn't the message that I'm now synchronized be printed later when I really received and verified those blocks?

Answer (score 3):

simple answer is those nodes are on a different, longer chain. how your node decides which chain is the "correct" chain, I don't know that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably just a glitch, or as werdwerdus said, the nodes are on a different longer chain.